# Is it normal/advised to finish your masters to get a better PhD offer?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

Let's say someone finishes their honours degree and would like to do their PhD.

However, the scholarship offers they receive aren't at the places they'd have hoped.

My question is whether it is worth doing an additional year to finish their masters with the hope of getting into their preferred university.

My personal situation is that I would like to study in Singapore or Hong Kong, but only received offers from Australian universities.

Comment: In addition to the above possible duplicate questions, you may also be interested in the following question: [How do weak students who want to do PhD's get into masters programmes in the first place?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48553)